# is it possible to css design an element inside an echo

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli

I follow a tutorial to make a table with paging and what i want to do is if possible.. to design the links, (123) in the blue background at the top like adding padding because they are too cramped, color:white, etc. and put it below the table. Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table class="reservations-table">
        <thead>
            <th class="thFirstName">First Name</th>
            <th class="thLastName">Last Name</th>
            <th class="thEmailAddress">Email Address</th>
            <th class="thContactNumber">Contact Number</th>
            <th class="thSpeaker">Speaker</th>
            <th class="thTopic">Topic</th>
            <th class="thLocation">Location</th>
            <th class="thAudience">Audience</th>
            <th class="thCount">Count</th>
            <th class="thTime">Time</th>
            <th class="thDate">Date</th>
            <th class="thAction">Action</th>
        </thead>
    <?php

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "srdatabase";

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) 
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $results_per_page = 10;
        $select= "SELECT * FROM reservations";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
        $number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if(!isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }

        $this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM reservations LIMIT " . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row['firstname']."</td>
                <td>".$row['lastname']."</td>
                <td>".$row['emailaddress']."</td>
                <td>".$row['contactnumber']."</td>
                <td>".$row['speaker']."</td>
                <td>".$row['topic']."</td>
                <td>".$row['location']."</td>
                <td>".$row['audience']."</td>
                <td>".$row['count']."</td>
                <td>".$row['time']."</td>
                <td>".$row['date']."</td>
                <td align='center'><a href='adminControl.php?epr=delete&id=".$row['id']."'>DELETE</a></td>
            </tr>";         
        }

        $number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results/$results_per_page);

    ?>

    <center>
    <div id="paging-div">

    //paging link 123

    <?php
        for($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++)
        {
            echo '<a href="adminControl.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: First of all, I don't see `<tr>` inside the `<<thead>`, so you need to wrap the current cells with `<tr></tr>` and above, add `<tr><th colspan="12">123</th></tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `<tbody>` and close `<tbody>` after `</thead>` . Beside please close table tag `</table>`

Please try like below

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table class="reservations-table">
    <thead>
        <th class="thFirstName">First Name</th>
        <th class="thLastName">Last Name</th>
        <th class="thEmailAddress">Email Address</th>
        <th class="thContactNumber">Contact Number</th>
        <th class="thSpeaker">Speaker</th>
        <th class="thTopic">Topic</th>
        <th class="thLocation">Location</th>
        <th class="thAudience">Audience</th>
        <th class="thCount">Count</th>
        <th class="thTime">Time</th>
        <th class="thDate">Date</th>
        <th class="thAction">Action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "cktest01";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $results_per_page = 10;
    $select= "SELECT * FROM reservations";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
    $number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if(!isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }

    $this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM reservations LIMIT " . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>
            <td>".$row['firstname']."</td>
            <td>".$row['lastname']."</td>
            <td>".$row['emailaddress']."</td>
            <td>".$row['contactnumber']."</td>
            <td>".$row['speaker']."</td>
            <td>".$row['topic']."</td>
            <td>".$row['location']."</td>
            <td>".$row['audience']."</td>
            <td>".$row['count']."</td>
            <td>".$row['time']."</td>
            <td>".$row['date']."</td>
            <td align='center'><a href='adminControl.php?epr=delete&id=".$row['id']."'>DELETE</a></td>
        </tr>";         
    }

    $number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results/$results_per_page);

?>
</tbody>
</table>


<div id="paging-div">

<!-- paging link 123 -->

<?php
    for($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++)
    {
        echo '<a style="color:green" href="adminControl.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a>';
    }
?>

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: um may ask what is the use of <tbody> ? and about the table closing tag its already close but i think i didnt copy it when i paste the code.

Comment: Since you used <thead> tag, so i use <tbody> because it is standard. Please know more below the link. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp

Comment: You can style a tag using style attribute(<a style="color:green" href="your link"> your link test </a>) . Please know more below the link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want in detail, but of course you can add CSS `style` attributes to your echoed HTML.

An example (watch the `td` tags):

```
echo "<tr>
            <td style='background:#fca;'>".$row['firstname']."</td>
            <td 'background:#cfb;'>".$row['lastname']."</td> 
etc.....
```

Note: I used single quotes for the quotes which mark the `style` atrribute value. Those won't interfere with the double quotes you use for echoeing.

Comment: what i want to do is style the <a> tag in this code "for($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++)
       {
            echo '<a href="adminControl.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a>';
        }"    is it possible to style it directly like you do in your example or add an id to it so i can style it with css

Comment: @Red You can style like echo '<a style="color:red;" href="adminControl.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a>'; In Style, You can write desired css.

Comment: nc. this is what i want to do. but im sure i already try this, maybe because i didnt first clear my google cache. sometimes my css is not working and when i clear my history, cache its working again. can you post your answer so i can choose it as the write answer

Comment: @Red Please check my answer whose name is MD. ABDUL HALIM. I am that person. got it ?